# Property of Ring $\frac{Z[x]}{(x^2+x+1,x^3+2x^2+2x+6)}$

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

$\frac{Z[x]}{(x^2+x+1,x^3+2x^2+2x+6)}$

a) is an integral domain

b) is an finite ring

c) is a field

D)product of two rings

My attempt: I think the ideal $(x^2+x+1,x^3+2x^2+2x+6)$ is not maximal in $Z[x]$ hence option c is false. For another option I am not able to think so far.

Comment: The two polynomials are coprime.

Comment: if two elements are co prime, it means you can use Chinese Remainder theorem to write it in products of rings, further then you can analyse  the products individually to say about integral domainnes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that
$$
x^3+2x^2+2x+6=(x^2+x+1)(x+1)+5.
$$
Thus we have a coincidence of ideals
$$
(x^3+2x^2+2x+6,x^2+x+1)=(x^2+x+1,5).
$$
Now
$$
\frac{\mathbb{Z}[x]}{(x^2+x+1,5)}\simeq\frac{\mathbb{F}_5[x]}{(x^2+x+1)}
$$
where $\mathbb{F}_5$ is the field with $5$ elements.

The polynomial $x^2+x+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$ because it has no roots  in $\mathbb{F}_5$ and thus the quotient is $\mathbb{F}_{25}$, the field with $25$ elements.

Comment: Thankyou sir, I was thinking in wrong direction and didn't think of this approach